# Formik reset errors

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to reset all errors in the form.

I tried using `setErrors` and `setStatus`, none of these are working. Errors in Formik state is not getting cleared.

```
setErrors({errors: {}})
```

and

```
setStatus({ errors: {}});
```

None of the above worked.

`resetForm()` clears all errors, but the form values are also reset which I don't want. Any pointers to clear only the errors object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly use Formik's setError method? (React library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986962/how-to-properly-use-formiks-seterror-method-react-library)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While using `setErrors`, just pass the state of `errors` object you want. So to reset all errors, pass an empty object(`{}`).

```js
setErrors({})
```

Codesandbox [demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-instant-validation-example-u7dq9).

Comment: Can we do it with setStatus as setErrors is deprecated.?

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

What worked is:

```js
formik.setTouched({}, false);
```

Comment: this worked like a charm, thanks. Use case, reset form when close modal. (Form lives in modal)
in my case, I had to add a useEffect with a boolean variable as a dependency that toggles each time someone closes the modal pressing close button. Then useeffect has a return function so when component unmount it runs this  code you wrote.

 useEffect(() => {
   
    return function cleanUp() {
      formik.setTouched({}, false);
    };
  }, [isClose]);

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `form.setFieldTouched (fieldName, false, false)` to reset a single field.

Here is example where checking checkbox will clear the value and error form the `date` field.

```js
<Field name={'expiry'}>
  {({
    field,
    form,
  }) => (
    <Checkbox
      {...field}
      onChange={(e) => {
        field.onChange(e)
        form.setFieldValue('date', '')
        form.setFieldTouched('date', false, false)
      }}
    />
  )}
</Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and solved by adding

```
const { handleReset } = useFormikContext<any>()
...
handleReset()
```